# Calculations in PGFplots \addplot3 inline table

Tags: tables, pgfplots, calculations, inline

Plotting a rectangular patch with the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[patch,patch type=rectangle,table/row sep=\\,patch table={0 1 2 3\\}] table[row sep=\\]
            {%
                x y z \\
                0 0 0 \\ % 0
                -1 -1 0 \\ % 1
                -1 -1 1 \\ % 2
                0 0 1 \\ % 3
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

works fine, but

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[patch,patch type=rectangle,table/row sep=\\,patch table={0 1 2 3\\}] table[row sep=\\]
            {%
                x y z \\
                0 0 0 \\ % 0
                -1/sqrt(3) -1 0 \\ % 1 % USE OF SQRT!
                -1/sqrt(3) -1 1 \\ % 2 % USE OF SQRT!
                0 0 1 \\ % 3
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '-1/sqrt(3)' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '/sqrt(3)'..
```

How should I modify the code such that mathematical functions like `sqrt(...)` are allowed in a `PGFplots` inline `table` and do not give an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally TikZ runs **everything** through \pgfmathparse, but this is not the case here.  You will have to pre-format it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{-1/sqrt(3)}
\let\tempx=\pgfmathresult

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[patch,patch type=rectangle,table/row sep=\\,patch table={0 1 2 3\\}] table[row sep=\\]
            {%
                x y z \\
                0 0 0 \\ % 0
                {\tempx} -1 0 \\ % 1 % USE OF SQRT!
                {\tempx} -1 1 \\ % 2 % USE OF SQRT!
                0 0 1 \\ % 3
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And what do I do if I need `2/sqrt(3)`? I tried `-2\tempx` but it gives me a way too large number. I also need to use `3/sqrt(3)`, `4/sqrt(3)` and so on, so I'd rather not use a `\pgfmathparse{...}\let\tempx=\pgfmathresult` per number I need.

Comment: \tempx is a macro, not a dim.  For example, if \tempx contained 1, 2\tempx would be 21.

Comment: Okay, clear. But my question remains: what is the best way to construct the `1/sqrt(3)`, `2/sqrt(3)`, ... ? It would be nice not having to construct a `\pgfmathparse{...}\let\tempx=\pgfmathresult` for every one of them, but instead somehow using the earlier obtained result of `1/sqrt(3)`.

Comment: I've tried doing the entire table as a macro.  I've tried inline expansion.  I've tried \pgfextra.  So far this is the only thing that has worked.  BTW, you will need a different name for each calculated value: \tempa, \tempb, etc.